# Change highlight color of word occurrences in Find results window when using dark mode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When I click a word in the find results window (that I was popping up using Shift-F12 to get all accesses of a certain variable), all occurences of that word will be highlit.
When using dark mode, that makes the text unreadable as the color is near white. Where can I set the highlight color or disable the feature of showing those occurences differently?

The screenshot shows how I clicked the word "Single" and three lines up, the same word was highlit with a lilac color.

[image]

## edit

Got a suggestion that it would be "highlight written reference" under "Text editor", but it looks like this:
[image]

and that does not match the color. Changing it to black background does not alter occurrence appearances in the "Find results".

Comment: I *think* this is controlled by the Highlight Written Reference property in the Font and Colors sections in the Options: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQtGj.png You can try changing that around, but I find it odd that you have two different colors showing to begin with.

Comment: I tried it and updated the question @TimothyG.